# LM317t doesn't output as low as expected

Tags: voltage-regulator, lm317

I have an LM317t based variable power supply that I designed. According to the math on the regulator's datasheet my output range should be between 1.25v and 13.7v but after testing today my voltmeter measured 6.4v with the potentiometer at 0% and 13.7v at 100%

Does anyone with more experience with linear regulators know why the low end would be so far outside the mathematical calculation?

For reference I am using a 100ohm resistor and a 1k pot.

Edit:solved: voltage measurement was taken with no load, placed a resistor across the output.

Comment: Can you please provide a schematic and a photo of how your regulator is connected, showing input voltage and other details?

Comment: Are you measuring under load? The lm317 has a minimum load of 10mA for stability.

Comment: I am not measuring under any load no, is this just an issue of quiescent current instability?

Comment: 100\$\Omega\$ OUT to ADJ should provide more than sufficient load (12.5mA) if connected correctly.

Comment: You could add your edit as an answer for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the LM317T has a minimum load for stabilized voltage output. Below 10mA, the behavior will be erratic. This can vary in individual units. You could see a unexpected voltage or lots of oscillations. This is common in legacy regulators, newer designs are less prone to needing such a relatively high minimum load.